# matrix dimension error in matlab code

Tags: matlab, image-processing, watermark, bsxfun

i am trying a particular code in matlab but getting the error
`Error using ==> plus

Matrix dimensions must agree.`

at this line

```
LL_1=LL+k;
```

where `k=w*alpha;` and `[LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(X,'db1','d');` and `X=imread('cameraman.tif');
X=im2double(X);`
Please help me out how should i solve this error?

Edit: I went through one of the posts here and tried using bsxfun

```
LL_1=bsxfun(@plus,LL+k);
```

but this does not solve the problem

Edit 2:The code is about digital image watermarking using the dwt algorithm,i have found this code while browsing through the internet but it gives the errors i have discussed above.
I have posted the first half of the code till where i am getting the error.
I hope my reply is useful in solving the error

```
%loading cover image 
X=imread('cameraman.tif'); 
X=im2double(X); 
[F1,F2]=wfilters('db1','d'); 
[LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(X,'db1','d');

%watermark image 
b=imread('copyright.bmp'); 
level=graythresh(b); 
w=im2bw(b,level); 
w=double(w); 
alpha=0.09; 
k=w*alpha; 
LL_1=bsxfun(@plus, LL, k); 
Y=idwt2(LL_1,LH,HL,HH,'db1','d');
```

Comment: when you use `size` on the matrices you wrote, what do you get?
that is, `size(LL)` and `size(K)`

Comment: value of LL is:<171x210x3 double>  and value of k is:<273x286 double>

Comment: `size(LL)

ans =

   171   210     3` `size(k)

ans =

   273   286`

Comment: Your watermark image is larger than your cover image - is that allowed? Maybe you need to crop your watermark image down to 171 x 210 pixels?

Comment: @Dan i tried this but it still gives me an error at:`LL_1=bsxfun(@plus, LL, k);` the error is:  Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each
other.

Answer (score 1):

Try `bsxfun` like this:

```
LL_1=bsxfun(@plus, LL, k);
```

**Edit**:
Consolidating the answers from the above suggestion, the comments on Natan's answer and the new code the OP posted

```
%loading cover image 
X=imread('cameraman.tif'); 
X=im2double(X); 
[F1,F2]=wfilters('db1','d'); 
[LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(X,'db1','d');

%watermark image 
b=imread('copyright.bmp');
b=imresize(b,size(squeeze(LL(:, :, 1)));
level=graythresh(b); 
w=im2bw(b,level); 
w=double(w); 
alpha=0.09; 
k=w*alpha; 
LL_1=bsxfun(@plus, LL, k); 
Y=idwt2(LL_1,LH,HL,HH,'db1','d');
```

Comment: Hi i tried this but i am getting an error 'Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each
other.'

Comment: The please show output of `size()` on `LL` and `k` like @Count suggested

Comment: Is it this what you are asking? value of LL is:<171x210x3 double> and value of k is:<273x286 double>  I just posted the same to @Count's question

Comment: Yes so how exactly do you want to add these two? Not one of their dimensions match. I think you need to rewrite your question and include a lot more information about what you are trying to do and also the value of the inputs like `w`, `alpha` and `X` and the code in the order it is written

Comment: Please move this out of the comments and rather edit your question. It's hard to read here.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like a re-size of `b` to the size of `X` (or vice versa) will solve your issue. After you read `b` try,

```
 b=imresize(b,size(X))
```

Then the `bsxfun` that @Dan suggested should work...

Comment: i tried this but it still gives errors:  `Error using ==> iptcheckmap at 40
Function IMRESIZE expected its second input argument, MAP, to be a
valid colormap.
Valid colormaps cannot have values outside the range [0,1].

Error in ==> imresize>parsePreMethodArgs at 368
    iptcheckmap(map, mfilename, 'MAP', 2);

Error in ==> imresize>parseInputs at 263
[params.A, params.map, params.scale, params.output_size] = ...

Error in ==> imresize at 140
params = parseInputs(varargin{:});

Error in ==> dwtcode at 10
b=imresize(b,size(X));`

Comment: Then maybe try `b=imresize(b,size(squeeze(X(:, :, 1)))`

Comment: @Dan i tried the above suggestion but it still gives me an error at:`LL_1=bsxfun(@plus, LL, k);` the dimensions are not matching

Comment: What was the size of LL and of k this time? Basically for `bsxfun` to work `size(squeeze(L(:,:,1)))` must equal `size(k)`. If `X` and `LL` have different dimensions then you need `b=imresize(b,size(squeeze(LL(:, :, 1)))`. BTW the squeeze might not be necessary, check without it and if you don't get errors then leave it off.

Comment: i have wasted a lot of time on this but it is not working,i have left trying this and using another code for my project that works perfectly fine.